# Android Emulator: Unable to Start Activity Null Pointer Exception Handle Launch

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-emulator

The application can run fine on my real device, it can start up and run on the emulator, however, as I log in and reach the onCreate method it throws the error as seen below. The emulator has been set up with all required specifications such as correct API level and allowed use of SD card for memory (200 mib). Is there any insight into how to alleviate this error?

```
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625): Process: com.example.bestapp, PID: 625
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bestapp/com.example.best.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5042)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at com.example.bestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-24 10:19:53.060: E/AndroidRuntime(625):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2172)
```

MainActivity onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));


        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Context context;

        // Just test displaying
        lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
        lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());


    // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
    final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Populating the dropdown menu
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();


    // Get the present day
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    itemList.add("Today");
    if (today == 2) {
        itemList.add("Tues");
        itemList.add("Weds");
        itemList.add("Thurs");
        itemList.add("Fri");
    }
    if (today == 3) {
        itemList.add("Weds");
        itemList.add("Thurs");
        itemList.add("Fri");
        itemList.add("Sat");
    }
    if (today == 4) {
        itemList.add("Thurs");
        itemList.add("Fri");
        itemList.add("Sat");
        itemList.add("Sun");
    }
    if (today == 5) {
        itemList.add("Fri");
        itemList.add("Sat");
        itemList.add("Sun");
        itemList.add("Mon");
    }
    if (today == 6) {
        itemList.add("Sat");
        itemList.add("Sun");
        itemList.add("Mon");
        itemList.add("Tues");
    }
    if (today == 7) {
        itemList.add("Sun");
        itemList.add("Mon");
        itemList.add("Tues");
        itemList.add("Weds");
    }
    if (today == 1) {
        itemList.add("Mon");
        itemList.add("Tues");
        itemList.add("Weds");
        itemList.add("Thurs");
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            itemList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            return view;
        }


    };

    // Assign list to actionbar
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(aAdpt, null);

}
```

Comment: *Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);* getLastKnownLocation can return null

Comment: @blackbelt is there an improved way to prevent a null assignment?

Comment: which is line number 59 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: @blackbelt is there a better way to send GPS coordinates to the emulator, I have used DDMS and 'sent' coordinates manually, but perhaps the emulator does not receive them? Steps in order are: start app in emulator->send coordinates->log in-> app fails. Is this proper?

Comment: @eatlon I know but still it does not answer his question

Comment: @user2450263 line 59 is: lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());

Comment: set debug point at location manager, and debug the app with repeating the steps "send coordinates->log in->.." when it pauses at the first point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // get last location
    Location lastLoc = locMan
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (lastLoc == null) {
        lastLoc = locMan
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    double lastlat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
    double lastlng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
 LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lastlat, lastlng);
```

//In the case u need an example of Google Maps

```
 userMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lastLatLng)
            .title("You are here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
            .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
```

Comment: The error only occurs when running on the emulator not a real deivce. I send coordinates through DDMS but it still doesn't help. Will your implementation prevent that?

Comment: No it will not. i've added some code that worked for my emulator.

Comment: could you add back the code you had, this answer is now incomplete...what's in class LatLng...

Comment: it is added, i use this for adding markers, and zooming in to the current position (that code is not added) i can send u the whole class if u want, but in chat, as it is a long code

Comment: Thanks, it's far more robust